# Mutiple checkboxes to update text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a form that if have checked TransientDevice, ControllingFrequency, and InterEntity then put Yes in the result input.  How do I use multiple checkboxes to accomplish this?  It works with one checkbox now, the "test" checkbox. I am not sure how to check for more than one checkbox.

```
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_test.asp">


        <input type="checkbox" name="TransientDevice" id="TransientDevice" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="DynamicResponse" id="DynamicResponse" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ControllingFrequency" id="ControllingFrequency" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ControllingVoltage" id="ControllingVoltage" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="InterEntity" id="InterEntity" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="ReliabilityImpact" id="ReliabilityImpact" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="checkbox" value="" />
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        $('#test').change(function() {
            $("#result").val(($(this).is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "");

        });
    });              
        </script>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're asking for:

```js
$('#TransientDevice, #ControllingFrequency, #InterEntity').change(function() {
  $("#result").val(($('#TransientDevice').is(':checked') && $('#ControllingFrequency').is(':checked') && $('#InterEntity').is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add_test.asp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="TransientDevice" id="TransientDevice" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="DynamicResponse" id="DynamicResponse" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ControllingFrequency" id="ControllingFrequency" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ControllingVoltage" id="ControllingVoltage" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="InterEntity" id="InterEntity" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ReliabilityImpact" id="ReliabilityImpact" value="" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" class="checkbox" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think this is what OP is asking for, I am deleting my answer.